# Sliding Popup In Silverlight

Tags: silverlight-4.0, popup, expression-blend, sliding

I've one requirement to implement a popup in Silverlight 4.0 when user hovers mouse over some control. And the popup should slide out from the control. I can show a popup. But can't give a sliding effect to it. Please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using rectangles with a drop shadow for sliding type "popups". You can disable the background if you need a modal type.

This is using pure xaml but the storyboards can be called from codebehind.

Reference to interactivity

```
   xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
 xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions" x:Class="SomeProject"
```

I'm using navigation pages so my code for the slide in and out transitions look as follows.

```
 <navigation:Page.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Name="Storyboard_Enter">
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)" Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="520"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
        <Storyboard x:Name="Storyboard_GoBack">
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)" Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle">
                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="520"/>
                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="0"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
    </navigation:Page.Resources>
```

The LayoutRoot

```
 <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Button x:Name="btnEnter" Content="Enter" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="48" Margin="96,88,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="144">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseEnter" SourceName="btnEnter">
                    <ei:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource Storyboard_Enter}"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </Button>
        <Rectangle x:Name="rectangle" Fill="#FF393939" Margin="-376,232,0,72" Stroke="Black" RadiusY="25" RadiusX="21" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="358" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                <CompositeTransform/>
            </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
            <Rectangle.Effect>
                <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="15" Color="#FFBABABA"/>
            </Rectangle.Effect>
        </Rectangle>
        <Button x:Name="btnGoBack" Content="Exit" Height="48" Margin="296,88,192,0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseEnter" SourceName="btnGoBack">
                    <ei:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource Storyboard_GoBack}"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </Button>

    </Grid>
```

This is a very crude example but should get you started.

We have the "popup" container sitting out of view right on the very edge of the main canvas.

Create storyboards to slide it in and slide it back.

Storyboards can be called with xaml based triggers or from codebehind.